# Отсутствие файла проекта в MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, linux, linux-mint, monodevelop

При сборке проекта пишет следующее:

> Cannot open assembly '/home/ivan/just_project/just_project/bin/Debug/just_project.exe': Нет такого файла или каталога

помогите решить проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файл по указанному пути существует? Если да, имеет смысл проверить наличие атрибута `x`.

Comment: just_project.exe почему-то не существует в той папке

Comment: ошибку нужно писать текстом в виде цитаты(в теге цитаты), а не только картинку вставлять.

Comment: Пишет, что построение завершилось успешно, значит нужно поискать по файловой системе куда оно записалось. Посмотрите настройки MonoDevelop, что там сказано на предмет путей сохранения.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить mono-msc (есть в менеджере программ).

Comment: К сожалению не могу проверить, так как вопрос был задан давно и уже стоит другая ОС